# Create and insert informations (indivituals) into an OWL ontology or into RDF file

Tags: java, jena, ontology, virtuoso

what is the best practice ?

I have created an ontology using Protege in OWL-DL, and i want to, use Jena API for JAVA, to populate it with instances (individuals) by importing informations from a file.

Do i have and is it possible to import the information's  :

- *Methode 1* : into my **existing OWL ontology** using "Jena Ontology API".
  or
- *Methode 2* : into a **new RDF file** using "Jena RDF API". In this case,
  how to be sure that instances satisfy the descriptions of defined
  classes in my OWL ontology.

PS: I must take into account the RAM memory by using methods that write instances in a persistent model, because I have a huge number of instances.

Answer (score 0):

When populating an ontology I advice for patience, which directly translates to not making any change done from outside Protege a permanent and un-undoable (inconsistencies may appear)

So, speaking clearlier, read the ontology into the model you will use through your Java program and save/write it into a diferent file.